# How can I transfer a file through a LAN and specify what adapter to use?

Tags: ethernet, lan, transfer

I'm using Windows 7.

I want to transfer a file from my desktop machine to my laptop. When I transfer it uses the Wifi automatically. Speed of transfer is like 700kbps.

If I shut off my wireless and plugin an ethernet cable, speeds are 10MBps. I can then turn on the internet and use it **while** the file is transfering through the cable.

How can I achieve the same result without having to switch off my wireless?

Comment: Is the Ethernet cable plugged into your wireless router or is it going directly to the laptop? Also what happens if you leave the wireless on and just plug in the Ethernet cable?

Comment: @Josh King: The ethernet cable is plugged in directly to the other machine. Point to point. There is a wireless router in my house so we sometimes use that to transfer files, but I need to be able trasnfer via the cable WITHOUT having to turn off my wireless adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the command-line `route` utility. You will want to use `route add` to create an entry that tells all LAN traffic destined for the other PC to go through your Ethernet interface.

Syntax example:

```
 > route ADD 192.168.0.99 MASK 255.255.255.0  192.168.0.254 METRIC 3 IF 2
          destination^              ^mask         ^gateway  metric^     ^
                                                               Interface^
```

you can get the interface number by running a `route print`.

```
C:\Users\John>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 16...00 1f 3a fd 8c 64 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 12...00 1d e0 b2 98 db ......Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link
 11...00 1e 37 88 e1 62 ......Intel(R) Gigabit Network Connection
 19...08 00 27 00 e4 f7 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 33...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 34...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================
```